# Spring hibernate error OneToMany Relationship: Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a One to Many relationship, one Match has many Events.
When spring tries to make this Match entity, I get the following error:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'match (id bigint not null auto_increment, date varchar(255),
>   loser varchar(255),' at line 1

Here is my Match.java

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id"))
public class Match {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String victor;
    private String loser;
    private String date;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "matches_events",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "match_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "event_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Event> events;

    public Match(String victor, String loser, String date) {
        super();
        this.victor = victor;
        this.loser = loser;
        this.date = date;
    }

public Match() {
    super();
}



    public Match(String victor, String loser, String date, Collection<Event> events) {
        super();
        this.victor = victor;
        this.loser = loser;
        this.date = date;
        this.events = events;
    }

    //Getters and setters...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql "match" is a reserved word for the [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). Change the name of your table, or change the mappings and it will work fine.

Comment: What do you mean by change the mappings?

Comment: By default, spring maps the class name with a table name, by replacing the camelcase with underscores. For instance, "Match" becomes "match" and "MyBeautifulTable" becomes "my_beautiful_table". If you wish, you can keep the class name to Match, and annotate it with @Table(name="game_match") or whatever you like to replace the default mapping.